Как сделать шаблон без подключения к базе данных а Jasper studio 7?
Мне нужно сделать шаблон без подключения к базе данных, я использую Java для отправки данных, не знаю, как лучше это сделать. Какой инструмент лучше использовать, чтобы получилось как на картинке? Мне нужно что бы все это было динамически без зашития текста. Я использую вложенный параметр:
 statements: [ {
    currency: {
            code: "KZT",
            symbol: "т"
        },
     accountNumber : KZ709480007A05124224,
                    accountNumber " 
    amountFrom: 100000,
    amountTo: 80000,
    income: 6000,
    outcome: 26000  
 } ],


